# Does anyone else have a problem running the debugger for air in Flexbuilder 4.5 using flex sdk 4.5 on Windows 7?

Tags: air, flexbuilder

I get the error "Process has terminated without establishing a connection to debugger". 
The application.xml file is configured properly with the correct air version. This was a reported issue.

I have installed : 
   adobe air 2.6
   Flexbuilder 4.5
   most recent flex sdk 4.5

I am running windows 7 home premium x64.
I have installed the same components on Windows xp and windows 7 ultimate x64 and the debugger runs fine! 
I've uninstalled / reinstalled, turned off anti-virus, turned off firewalls. 
PLEASE!!!! HELP!! haha.

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured out my problem..
For some reason my hosts file had localhost improperly set. 
0.0.0.0 localhost    lol definitely not right! 
Once I set it correctly the debugger sprang to life.